# Adding to Java classpath breaks ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I wanted to have a certain JAR in my classpath for easy access with a Jython REPL. So in my .bashrc I put:

```
export CLASSPATH=:/home/tmacdonald/path/to/jar/thing.jar
```

However, this breaks ant both for compiling that JAR can compiling a JAR from a different subpackage:

```
$ ant jar
Invalid implementation version between Ant core and Ant optional tasks.
 core    : 1.8.0 in file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar
 optional: 1.5.1 in file:/home/tmacdonald/path/to/jar/lib/gt2-2.3.3/ant-optional-1.5.1.jar
$ echo $CLASSPATH
:/home/tmacdonald/path/to/jar/thing.jar
```

Changing the classpath fixes it:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=
$ !ec
echo $CLASSPATH

$ ant jar
[Compiles successfully.]
```

But it seems awkward and not The Right Thing to have to keep changing my classpath, depending on whether I wanted to run ant or a Jython REPL. I'll admit that my knowledge of both ant and the classpath is pretty weak. I just think of the classpath as being, "PATH for Java libraries; or PYTHONPATH for Java", and I only ever add small changes to existing ant config files I inherited--I've never had to set one up.

So I'd be interested to hear what's really happening (and incidentally how that causes my problem) so I can be a little bit more educated, and of course I'd also like a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Ant should know or care about environment variables.  The right way to do it is to set CLASSPATH inside the Ant build.xml itself.

Here are production and test classpaths that I use in my Ant build.xml files:

```
<path id="production.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${production.classes}"/>
    <pathelement location="${production.resources}"/>
    <fileset dir="${production.lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="test.class.path">                            
    <path refid="production.class.path"/>
    <pathelement location="${test.classes}"/>
    <pathelement location="${test.resources}"/>
    <fileset dir="${test.lib}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

As you can see, there are no references to `${classpath}`, nor should there be.

Comment: Well most of the classpath references in build.xml look something like this: `<classpath path="${classpath}" />`. I'm assuming `${classpath}` refers to the environment variable, but could be wrong. If so, it doesn't seem future-proof to change it to `<classpath path="">` and frustrate developers who were expecting something else.

Comment: duffyco is completely correct. It's extremely important to keep the compilation classpath separate from the environment classpath. Remember ANT is also a java program, that is what the environment classpath is for :-)

Comment: You shouldn't have an environment variable named CLASSPATH.  I don't have one on any machine that I use.

Comment: trivia: having a system CLASSPATH also breaks beanshell.  this is the side-effect of having a custom class-loader.